# Get the URL of a Page in an iFrame from this, Child Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iframe

There are loads and loads of articles on here where people are trying to find the parent URL from within an iFrame.

I'm not trying to do that, I simply want to know the URL of the current page with Javascript.

For some reason this seems difficult, but I can see no reason why!

So, to explain thoroughly.

My parent page HTML looks like

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="mainWindow" name="mainWindow" src="myMainPage.aspx" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>
    <iframe src="myOtherPage.aspx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE; the `style` for the top frame makes it fill the screen. This is important as the only reason I am using iFrames is so that the second frame can be used to run a couple of pseudo background tasks, via a Javascript timer as I cannot use server controlled background tasks (long story).

So, although we have frames here, I'm really not using the frame to create framed layouts, but to ensure the primary page remains static whilst a user is live on my application (this is a back-end CMS system, not a live customer facing website)

So, basically, everything, except my background service functions is carried out from within the main iFrame itself, the parent page never really gets reloaded, and the hidden frame just does stuff as required, but ensures it's not interrupted by page unloads.

On occasion, I need to know the URL of the page that is present in the main window.

I don't really understand why

```
window.location.pathname
```

Doesn't work, but this gives me the URL of the parent window. (www.mysite.com/myParent.aspx)

```
document.URL
```

Also returns the parent URL

```
document.getElementById("mainWindow").contentWindow.location.href
```

Doesn't work, because the element does not exist within the iFrame, as it is in the parent.

What I need is the current URL of the page which is loaded into the iFrame, from within the iFrame itself. So, quite simply

```
What is the URL of the page on which this javascript is loaded
```

This is because I am loading scripts on a MasterPage which do slightly different things on different pages.

Comment: Maybe `top.frames['mainWindow'].window.location`?

Comment: Or, `top.frames[window.name].window.location` from within the `iframe` without knowing the frame name you're working with (as long as it has one).

Comment: Got myself confused now. I moved the script in the page and now it works. Gotta call it a day now but I'll check it again tomorrow I think.